# OpenFileDialog extensions similar to MS Paint's SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, openfiledialog, image-formats

I am working on a WPF application where users will be able to upload photos. I wrote the following code for the file extensions.

```
    OpenFIleDialog.Filter = "JPEG Images|*.jpg|PNG Images|*.png|GIF Images|*.gif|BITMAPS|*.bmp|TIFF Images|*.tiff|TIFF Images|*.tif";
```

When saving a file in ms paint we have options as following
[image]

here we can see that the same format (.bmp & .dib) is being used for 4 options.

My question is can this be done using OpenFileDialog. If so, how?

Answer (score 5):

Its quite simple, just add your filter like this

```
openFileDialog.Filter = "Office Files(Document or Excel)|*.doc;*.docx;*.xlsx;*.xls|Word Document(*.doc *.docx)|*.doc;*.docx";
var result = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                var selectedFile = openFileDialog.FileName;
                var filterIndex = openFileDialog.FilterIndex;
                if(filterIndex == 1)
                { 
                   /* Code to perform if first filter (Office files in this case) is selected */ 
                }
                else if (filterIndex == 2)
                { 
                   /* Code to perform if second filter (Word Document in this case) is selected */
                }
```

Here you can see that *.doc & *.docx are repeated. So based upon the selected value you can decide which encoding (in your case) to apply.

Comment: Will that save the files in separate formats? I mean when using mono|| 16 color||256 color||24 - bit , the  variation in the file saved is clear. The extension is always .bmp but the picture quality is different. How will the openfiledialog know if all the formats show as .bmp (here .doc or .docx). Will the string visible to the user make any difference.

Comment: @Raj123 I have added some more code where you can achieve the purpose with the FilterIndex property of OpenFileDialog.

Comment: OpenFileDialog just produces a string, nothing more and nothing less.  It is up to you to identify the real kind of image format.  Which is almost never a problem, a method like Image.FromFile() figures it out by itself from the file header and pays no attention to the filename extension.